# Delphi: splitter resizes only 2 panes which it splits

Tags: delphi, splitter

I have 4 panels, in a row, with 3 splitters in between. 1st/2nd/3rd panes: `align=alLeft`, 4th pane: `align=alClient`.

`[1] | [2] | [3] | [4]`

Now user wants, that

- splitter 1 resizes only panels 1 and 2 (don't touch others; now it moves panels 3/4)
- splitter 2 resizes only panels 2 and 3 (don't touch others; now it moves panel 4)

How to do this, what events to handle (`TSplitter.OnMoved` of course) and how to handle them? Maybe don't set `Align` like now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that Splitter 3 (last) shall only change Panel 3 and 4, this can be done with a little bit of nesting:

1. The top level has PanelA (alLeft), Splitter3 (alLeft), Panel4 (alClient).
2. PanelA contains PanelB (alLeft), Splitter2 (alLeft), Panel3 (alClient).
3. PanelB contains Panel1 (alLeft), Splitter1 (alLeft), Panel2 (alClient).